# Probability of getting a good haircut

Tags: probability

The local barber shop is home to three barbers, Adam, Bob and Carl.

The barbers appear identical but vary in their ability to provide good haircuts.

The probability that you receive a good haircut in this barber shop is 3/5. The probability that any particular barber cuts your hair is 1/3. The probability that you receive a good haircut from Adam is 1. The probability that you receive a good haircut from Bob is 1/2.

Suppose that you have visited the barber shop only once and received a good haircut. Assume also that the barber who cut your hair on the first visit will cut your hair on the second visit.

Determine the probability that you will get a good haircut in your second visit.

So we have $P(G) = \frac{3}{5}$, or $0.6$

$P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = \frac{1}{3}$

$P(G|A) = 1$

$P(G|B) = 0.5$

$P(G|C) = 0.3$ (Found by taking: $0.6 (\text{total success rate}) - (\frac{1}{3} \cdot 1) - (\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}) = 0.1 \implies \frac{0.1}{1/3} = 0.3)$

Now this is where I am stuck. I need to determine the probability of success on the second visit but don't really have a clue how to.

Comment: "probability that you receive a good haircut in this barber shop is 5 3" What?

Comment: Did you mean the probability you receive a good haircut in this barbershop is $\frac{3}{5}$?

Comment: Yes, this is my first time posting so my formatting was a bit off but it has been rectified it seems

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ denote the event of getting a good haircut, and let $A,B,C$ denote the respective events of getting a haircut from Adam, Bob, and Carl.

You need to find the probability that the haircut came from $A,B,$ and $C$ **given** that it was a good  haircut. You can use Bayes' Theorem.

We have

$$\mathsf P(A\mid G)=\frac{\mathsf P(A\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot1}{\frac{3}{5}}=\frac{5}{9}$$

$$\mathsf P(B\mid G)=\frac{\mathsf P(B\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{5}}=\frac{5}{18}$$

$$\mathsf P(C\mid G)=\frac{\mathsf P(C\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot0.3}{\frac{3}{5}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Now that you have these probabilities, can find $\mathsf P(G)$ by weighting accordingly?

Comment: I believe so, now I just have to multiply 5/9 by 1, 5/18 by 0.5 and 1/6 by 0.3 and add them together and that would be my final outcome right?

Comment: That would be correct!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Having received a good haircut the first time, the chance it was from $A$ is $\frac 1{1+0.5+0.3}$ and similarly for the other two.  That becomes the chance that $A$ cuts your hair the second time.